# Can't find org.gnome.shell.recorder in gsettings

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

I am trying to do screen recording on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and supposedly pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> will do it.

In order to get audio I found on a different post that I need to run the command:

> gsettings set org.gnome.shell.recorder pipeline "queue ! videorate !
>   vp8enc quality=10 speed=2 ! mux. pulsesrc ! audio/x-raw-int ! queue !
>   audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! mux. webmmux name=mux"

However when I run this I get `No such schema org.gnome.shell.recorder`.

How can I fix this? Do I need to install the schema somehow? I have been unable to find anything on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just because you're not running GNOME Shell, I guess that you're running Ubuntu Unity, not the GNOME variant.

To record screencast with sound, just install recordMyDesktop:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gtk-recordmydesktop/